# StoredProcedureQuery with multiple OUT parameter always throws expection

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures

I have procedure with IN/OUT parameter as follows:

```
PROCEDURE procedureName(p_esp_message_id                 VARCHAR2,
                               p_esp_message_id_dt              DATE,
                               p_event_bus_channel              VARCHAR2,
                               p_esp_event_type                 VARCHAR2,
                               p_event_source_system            VARCHAR2,
                               p_event_create_dt                DATE,
                               p_status                         VARCHAR2,
                               p_returned_at                    TIMESTAMP,
                               p_remaining_payments             NUMBER,
                               p_balance_owed                   NUMBER,
                               p_eclb_equip_remaining_amt       NUMBER,
                               p_trade_in_credit_amount         NUMBER,
                               p_last_installment               NUMBER,
                               p_equipment_id                   VARCHAR2,
                               p_reason_id                      VARCHAR2,
                               p_equip_level_status                VARCHAR2,
                               p_fin_type_cd                    VARCHAR2,
                               p_ulid                           VARCHAR2,                            
                               p_guid                           VARCHAR2,
                               p_event_receive_status       OUT VARCHAR2,
                               p_event_error_code           OUT VARCHAR2,
                               p_event_receive_id           OUT NUMBER);
```

And I have implemented the java class which will call the stored procedure as follows:

```
@Service
public class DatabaseService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DatabaseService.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void updateLoanStatusInformationToScms(LoanStatusDTO loanStatusDTO) throws ParseException {
        // long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("Start - DatabaseService.updateLoanStatusInformationToScms");

        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = null;
        //HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date now = new java.sql.Date(simpleDateFormat.parse("2018-09-12").getTime());
        String SCMSResponse = null;
        List<String> inputPrameterList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            storedProcedure = em
                    .createStoredProcedureQuery("procedurename");

            setInputParameter("p_esp_message_id", String.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getEventMessageId(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_esp_message_id_dt", Date.class,
                    now, storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_event_bus_channel", String.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getEventBusChannel(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_esp_event_type", String.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getEventName(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_event_source_system", String.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getEventSourceSystem(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_event_create_dt", Date.class,
                    now, storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);


            setInputParameter("p_status", String.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getStatus(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);

            setInputParameter("p_returned_at", Timestamp.class, loanStatusDTO.getReturnedDate(),
                    storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_remaining_payments", Integer.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getRemainingPayments(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);

            setInputParameter("p_balance_owed", Double.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getBalanceOwed(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);

            setInputParameter("p_eclb_equip_remaining_amt", Double.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getEquipmentRemainingAmount(),
                    storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_trade_in_credit_amount", Double.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getTradeInCreditAmount(), storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_last_installment", Double.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getLastInstallment(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_equipment_id", String.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getEquipmentId(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_reason_id", String.class, loanStatusDTO.getReasonId(),
                    storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_equip_level_status", String.class,
                    loanStatusDTO.getEquipmentLevelStatus(), storedProcedure,
                    inputPrameterList);
            setInputParameter("p_fin_type_cd", String.class, loanStatusDTO.getFinanceTypeCode(),
                    storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);

            setInputParameter("p_ulid", String.class, loanStatusDTO.getUlid(),
                    storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);

            setInputParameter("p_guid", String.class, loanStatusDTO.getGuid(),
                    storedProcedure, inputPrameterList);
            registerOutputParameter("p_event_receive_status", String.class,
                    storedProcedure);
            registerOutputParameter("p_event_error_code", String.class,
                    storedProcedure);
            registerOutputParameter("p_event_receive_id", Integer.class,
                    storedProcedure);

            storedProcedure.execute();
            String status = (String) storedProcedure
                    .getOutputParameterValue("p_event_receive_status");
            String code = (String) storedProcedure
                    .getOutputParameterValue("p_event_error_code");
            String id = String.valueOf(storedProcedure
                    .getOutputParameterValue("p_event_receive_id"));


            em.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //httpStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {


        }

    }

    private void setInputParameter(String parameterName,
            Class<?> parameterTypeClass, Object parameterValue,
            StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure, List<String> InputPrameterList) {
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(parameterName,
                parameterTypeClass, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.setParameter(parameterName, parameterValue);
        LOGGER.info(parameterName + ":" + parameterValue);
        InputPrameterList.add(parameterName + ":" + parameterValue);
    }

    private void registerOutputParameter(String parameterName,
            Class<?> parameterTypeClass, StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure) {
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(parameterName,
                parameterTypeClass, ParameterMode.OUT);
    }
}
```

When I run the application, it always shows the error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:224)
    at com.tmobile.finance.commissions.service.DatabaseService.updateLoanStatusInformationToScms(DatabaseService.java:114)
    at com.tmobile.finance.commissions.service.DatabaseService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$53f7f082.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.tmobile.finance.commissions.service.DatabaseService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cfc6cdb0.updateLoanStatusInformationToScms(<generated>)
    at com.tmobile.deep.scms.LoanProcessor.process(LoanProcessor.java:87)
    at com.tmobile.deep.scms.LoanProcessor.process(LoanProcessor.java:39)
    at com.tmobile.deep.scms.LoanProcessor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d998e23a.process(<generated>)
    at com.tmobile.deep.AMQPEventConsumer.handleMessage(AMQPEventConsumer.java:244)
    at com.tmobile.deep.AMQPEventConsumer.handleMessageSupplier(AMQPEventConsumer.java:125)
    at com.tmobile.deep.AMQPEventConsumer.lambda$handleDelivery$0(AMQPEventConsumer.java:89)
    at com.tmobile.deep.PauseListenersHystrixCommand.run(PauseListenersHystrixCommand.java:30)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10247)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10214)
    at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:411)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344)
    at com.tmobile.deep.AMQPEventConsumer.handleDelivery(AMQPEventConsumer.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.setNamedParameters(OracleSql.java:197)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:5615)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:52)
    ... 88 more
```

I have checked the count and name of the IN/OUT parameter, it was same as the database procedure. Can anyone please suggest me what I was wrong here.

Comment: What hibernate version are you using ?

Comment: @KeatsPeeks  am using 5.0.12.Final version

Comment: ok, I thought it was this bug : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10756 but if you're using 5.0.12 it should be fixed.